# interactive cd-rom software

Tags: flash, interface, cd

Could someone please recommend any software that can be used to create interactive CDROMs?

we have a possible job whereby an interactive CD ROM with basic animation is required. Company information is to be placed in various "Pages", and if possible some kind of "catalogue system" for a lot of PDFs would be available.

Any suggestions?

I've seen some existing CD ROM makers but they all look really cheap and unprofessional (like cheesy banners and colours etc) - what would you recommend?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's while since I used it, but [Adobe Director](http://www.adobe.com/products/director/) (or Macromedia Director as I know it as!) was good.   Lots of built in functionality, and also has the 'Lingo' scripting language if you want to do anything clever (and by the looks of things now also supports JavaScript).